# Need help to solve PDE with Matlab using pdepe

Tags: matlab, pde

I am totally new to Matlab and I just want to use it to solve the following system of coupled PDEs.
[image: System of pdes to solve]

After some research, I tried to use the `pdepe` function but I am struggling to understand how to make it work correctly and how to adapt my equations to it.
I have the following code (used x=y and E=t):

```
function [c,f,s] = pdefun(y,E, u,dy_dE)
    e = 1.602 * 10^-19;
    EPS = 1; 
    homega = 0.15 * e;
    l_p = 10 * 10^-9;
    l_e = 300 * 10^-9;
    
    c = [e*EPS; e*EPS];
    f = [-1;-1]; 
    g_D = u(1);
    g_G = u(2);
    source_left = ((1-g_G)*g_D -g_G*(1-g_D))/l_p + (g_D - g_G)/l_e;
    s = [ 0; source_left]; % Termes sources
end
function g = pdeic(x)
    g_D_initial = 0;
    g_G_initial = 0;
    
    g = [g_D_initial; g_G_initial];
end
function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = pdebc(yl,ul,yr,ur,E)
    pl = ?
    ql = ?
    pr = ?
    qr = ? 
end
```

I am encountering the following issues:

1. In pdefun, how do I tell Matlab to look for other values of g_D and g_G, to be able to look for values at E+homega and E-homega ?
2. I can't figure out how to translate my boundary conditions for the pdebc function.

Can someone help me solve these issues? Can even `pdepe` solve this system?

Thanks in advance,